# Finite fixpoint of the big union operator

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $x$ be a finite set, and consider $\bigcup x$. If $\bigcup x = x$, must $x$ be the empty set?

Comment: What do you mean by $\cup x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Assume $\bigcup x=x$ and $x\neq \emptyset$ for some finite $x$.

Because $x$ is finite and nonempty, there exists a $y\in x$ of maximal *rank* (i.e., nesting depth of $\{\}$), and we have $rank(x)=rank(y)+1$.

On the other hand, all elements of $\bigcup x$ are elements of elements of $x$, and therefore have rank strictly lower than $y$. Therefore $rank(\bigcup x)\leq y$, and hence $rank(\bigcup x)< rank(x)$. This contradicts $\bigcup x=x$!